# What do daily builds of a specific version contain?

Tags: system-installation, daily-build

Is the [daily build](http://www.cdimage.ubuntu.com/focal/daily-live/current/) of Ubuntu (Focal Fossa 20.04.1) the exact same as the released Ubuntu 20.04.1 after i would execute `apt-get update/upgrade` ?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.2 which currently is still in *development* or the *testing* phase.

Answer (score 0):

The daily build

http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/408/builds

will become 20.04.2 when it's released. It's currently not getting much attention, as it means little until the *groovy* stack (ie. 5.8 kernel etc) is completely *stable*.

All attention currently is still on getting *groovy* out, with any issues discovered fixed in *groovy*, which flow automatically back to *focal* daily (as 20.04.2 will use the *groovy* stack for HWE enabled installs).

Comment: View a page up http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/ to get a *glimpse* of where current development work is & testing is focused. It's not a complete picture, as the page is constantly change (eg. 16.04.7 or Xenial 16.04.7 wasn't expected so only appeared on that page a little over a week before it was released if I recall correctly).

Comment: so, the answer to my question is no? I am asking because i am hitting a bug in 20.04.1 which is fixed in the daily build. will i also get the fix when just doing an apt upgrade? unfortunately i cannot try it out right now.

Comment: No... To get some packages early you could enable *-proposed* https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed which will get you *fixes* early, however not all *fixes* make it to *stable* as extra *testing* is done whilst in *proposed* and if problems increase, they'll get backed out (this never reach *stable* or normal repositories). Using the Focal -proposed repository is more what you're after.. but does contain risks as it's still *testing* software/packages.